# Visual Studio 2012 - Get latest and list changed files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, getlatest

Is there a way to have visual studio 2012 list the files which were updated in the workspace by a get latest operation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah,  once you've done a get latest (or get specific or woteva), you can check the output window - make sure that the Show output from: is set to "Source Control - Team Foundation Server"

It'll look something like this after the get:

```
Replacing c:\tempcode\internal\UnitController.cs  
Replacing c:\tempcode\internal\PieSeriesData.cs
```

Not elegant i know.

**edit:**

When you have the Source Control Explorer open and have your project or project folder selected in the elft tree view, on the right the files are listed.  There is a column "Latest" indicates which files (in your workspace) are out of date and a column "Pending Changes" which indicate whether you have pending changes not yet pushed to server.  You can [before getting latest] right click on that file and compare with the server.

I'm sure there are other ways too

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder if another option is to compare the workspace with latest before getting latest.  If that works, I'll edit and add that as an option.